# where can I get mysql-5.1.7.tar.gz or mysql-5.1.9.tar.gz?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5, mysql-5.1

I need mysql-5.1.7.tar.gz or mysql-5.1.9.tar.gz, but I can not find them anywhere, who can give me a link to find them, thank you very much!!!

Comment: Here is a question : Why do you want MySQL 5.1.7 or MySQL 5.1.9 when neither release is GA? MySQL 5.1.30 is the first GA release of MySQL 5.1 ?

Comment: To the DBA.SE community : Don't close this yet. I found links to the two old versions !!!

Answer (score 2):

Please keep in mind

- MySQL 5.1.7

  - [released `March 06, 2006`](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?3,74195,74195#msg-74195)
  - still beta
- MySQL 5.1.30

  - [released `Dec 01, 2008`](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?3,236605,236605#msg-236605)
  - First GA Release
  - Bugs Cleaned Up in this version still exists in MySQL 5.1.7

Here are the MySQL / SkySQL Archives

- http://downloads.mysql.com/archives.php?p=mysql-5.1
- http://downloads.skysql.com/archive/index/p/mysql/v/5.1
- http://downloads.skysql.com/archives/mysql-5.1/
- The oldest (and only) pre-GA release of MySQL available for download is 5.1.5a

## RECOMMENDATION

If you have to use MySQL 5.1, go get MySQL 5.1.68 ([latest MySQL 5.1 released Feb 05, 2013](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?3,578481,578481#msg-578481))

## I FOUND IT !!!

- `MySQL 5.1.7` : http://www.findthatzipfile.com/search-9984545-fZIP/winrar-winzip-download-mysql-5.1.7-beta.tar.gz.htm
- `MySQL 5.1.9` : http://www.filewatcher.com/m/mysql-5.1.9-beta.tar.gz.21289244-0.html

## UPDATE 2013-03-19 11:05 EDT

OK, I have some bad news. According to MySQL (still hate saying Oracle, Yuck), that version was never released. Here is a bug report from Mar 15, 2013 : http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68678. From the desperate tone in the message, something tells me you submitted this to MySQL.

If you read a MySQL book from one of the original MySQL developers, he/she would have access to that unreleased version of MySQL. Your best shot would be to contact the book's author to get a copy of MySQL 5.1.8.

Comment: Thank you very much.I must have the mysql-5.1.7.tar.gz, and mysql-5.1.9.tar.gz. I need them , I need them .I have looked them for a very long time. I am desperate. thank you  anyway!!!!

Comment: I found them !!!

Comment: Thank you very much! In fact, I want to find mysql-5.1.8.tar.gz, but I can not find it anywhere. mysql-5.1.7.tar.gz, and mysql-5.1.9.tar.gz is the most similiar version of 5.1.8.tar.gz, so I want to have them . Could you help me find 5.1.8.tar.gz?? Thank you!